# registrating from outside a devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i'm currently working on a project with ruby on rails.
I generated a devise, the user can registrate/login.
it works perfectly.
now I added a link in the header of my website, "Become Supplier" that links to a form for filling the fields of a supplier.
everything works ok.
my problem is that when the user fills in the supplier form => the fields are all "NIL" in database.
its not getting updated !!

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def homeAdmin
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def fournisseur
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end
end
```

I get empty databse : every column is set to 'Nil' after filling in the form for a supplier !!
but i want my database to be populated !
i appreciate any help

Comment: Have you added the custom fields to the `configure_permitted_parameters` devise's method? The code that you have pasted is not related with your problem. If you don't have any error on create, you should see in the logs `Unpermitted parameters: your_custom_fields`

Comment: I don't know what is that, i'm a beginner in ruby on rails actually.
Can you please explain to me exactly what should be done ?

Comment: This gist should help you, step by step: https://gist.github.com/withoutwax/46a05861aa4750384df971b641170407. Tell me if you don't understand something

Comment: I added the costum fields to the configure_permitted_parameters devise's method.
after running " rails c" then " User.all"  I always get 'Nil' in the custom fields.
I don't know if i should add any methods in the user controller for creating or updating the new form .. ?

Comment: If you have a custom `registrations_controller` please add it to the post, with your registration's form (where there's the custom fields) and, also, add the logs after the new registration. I can't tell what is wrong without any code nor logs. :)